# How to fixed socket id for client socket.io

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I am developing a chat application in android with **socket.io** & **node.js** . Each and every time for a new connection, the **socket id** for a client is changed. So, to send a message to a specific user, I need another mandatory option like user registration with email or phone number. I keep **email**, **socket id** , **status** (online/offline) in **MySQL** database for a new client & **update** only the **socket id** when a registered user logs in again.

For the message, I store all the messages & send them to the recipient when he/she is logged in with a new socket id.

My questions:

1. Is there any option to **fix** a **socket id** for a client or not?
2. With the above explanation, am I walking in the right direction for a simple chatting application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I handled this was every time a user connects, I add them to object and save their username as the key and save the socket itself as the value. For example:

```
var connectedUsers = {};
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    connectedUsers[username] = socket;
});
```

then you can always grab their socket ID like so

```
var id = connectedUsers[username].id;
```

Comment: This essentially means that for every msg you need to pass the username for a lookup, right?